# Laravel update statement issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to run this update statement:

```
\DB::update('UPDATE order_items SET set_id = ? WHERE id IN (?)',[$model->id, '2,3,4']);
```

it should update order_items with ids `2` and `3` and `4`, but only order_item  `2` is updated and two other ids is ignored .

Comment: I'm no expert in laravel, but you wanna check with array('2','3','4');

Answer (score 1):

Try the Eloquent way

```
OrderItem::whereIn('id', [2,3,4])
         ->update(['set_id' => $model->id]);
```

Assuming you have a model for `order_items` as `OrderItem`.

Comment: Thanks it does work , but what is wrong with update statement?

Answer (score 0):

The correct laravel query builder is like bellow:

```
DB::table('order_items')->whereIn('id', [2, 3, 4])->update(['set_id' => $model->id]);
```

Comment: ErrorException in helpers.php line 747: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array